# Efficient Win32 Kernel Objects to be preferred over c++

Tags: c++, winapi

As a c++ programmer I try to stick to the standard and if that's not possible I try to use boost or some other portable lib. All in all, I like to write portable code. Now, the Windows SDK give you access to kernel objects which could lead to faster code as part of an optimization. I like to know which kernel objects do you like to use for efficiency?

One example would the Critical_Section but that one I believe is default choice for a mutex on Windows when using boost::threads or the c++11 concurrency. Sticking to intra-process concurrency, of course.

Let's leave out GUI programming for now. For that I like Qt which is good enough.

Comment: First off, this is "primarily opinion-based" and thus not fit for SO. (VTC) Second, any good cross-platform library (like boost) will use whatever platform-specific primitive which is the more relevant, either functionality-wise (but pretty much all platforms offer the same functionality) or performance-wise if it comes down to it. So IMHO your question is quite moot.

Comment: **winapi is a horrible mess**! From that point of view you might be right, that it's easy to misuse/getting abstractions wrong for efficient implementation of the c++11 thread and co.
But I think that any reputable framework like boost will get this right.

Comment: @g-makulik If only WinAPI was "just" a horrible mess, all would be fine. POSIX already *is* a horrible mess, and yet it's thousands times much more sane than WinAPI (disclaimer: just my opinion, the fact that I worked with both is of little importance). ;)

Comment: @syam Agreed ;-)! But it's like that: If a (c++11 compliant) compiler implementation or (reputable) framework claims to have these mechanisms, you can usually trust it.

Comment: @g-makulik Yeah, I was just responding to the bold part of your comment. Hell, that's the part that was supposed to get our attention, right? ;-) Blame extended beer'o'clock, don't take me too seriously at this time of the day. :-p (except when I'm being technical, of course, I never mess with this ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Generally kernel objects are not going to be more efficient. They take more RAM and using them requires an expensive context switch.

Critical sections are hybrids, they actually try to stay in user-mode and only create a kernel-mode semaphore if absolutely needed.

Your C++ standard library is probably loosely wrapping whatever the most efficient method for your platform is. Benchmark first.